# How can I tell if a soft contact lens is inside out?

Tags: eye, lenses

Soft contact lenses can be turned inside out. It then becomes difficult to know which is the right way around. This is especially a problem when I have put contact lenses in, then accidentally knocked one of them out due to forgetting I had them in and rubbing my eyes, for instance. At this point the contact lens may have twisted due to the fact that I rubbed my eyes. How can I tell which way is the right way around before I put the lens back in?

Comment: Hi, the questions aren't really the best place to provide health advice, so I have edited it out and left just the question.

Comment: I thought this might come up. I respect your call. I imagine, too, that allowing healthcare advice in this field could lead to sketchy advice being proffered in other fields, i.e. medication. @Lucky

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to check that, [allaboutvision.com](http://www.allaboutvision.com/) has some great information on various ways to check the orientation of a contact lens:

> **Method 1: The Side View**
>
> If your contact forms a perfect cup-shape with the edge perfectly
>   upright, the lens is correctly oriented and is ready to be placed on
>   your eye. If the edge has a noticeable outward bend (like a rimmed
>   soup bowl), the contact is inside out.
>
> **Method 2: The "Taco Test"**
>
> Place the contact lens between the tips of your thumb and forefinger,
>   grasping it near the center so the entire edge is free. Gently squeeze
>   the lens, as if you are about to fold it in half.
>
> If the edge of the lens points upward (resembling a hard-shell taco),
>   the lens is correctly oriented. If the edge bends outward (toward your
>   thumb and finger), the lens is inside out.
>
> **Method 3: Check The Edge Tint**
>
> If the color of the handling tint on the lens edge looks very blue (or
>   green, depending on the tint), the lens is correctly oriented. If the
>   color looks pale or washed out, the lens probably is inside out.
>
> **Method 4: Look For Laser Markings**
>
> Some contact lenses have a laser marking to help you determine if your
>   contact is inside out. For example, one brand has a "123" laser
>   marking near the edge of the lens.
>
> If the "123" appears normally, the lens is correctly oriented and
>   ready to be placed on your eye. If the "123" is backward, the contact
>   is inside out. If at first you don't see the laser marking, turn the
>   lens on your fingertip to make sure you check its entire surface.

Source: http://www.allaboutvision.com/contacts/faq/inside-out.htm

Comment: I am downvoting this answer because it is basically a copy-paste of the allaboutvision.com website. The copied-pasted text should at least be put into brackets (in the moment it's a pure plagiarism of another website and the author's work for this website). BW

Comment: I've queued an edit to improve the post formatting to make it clear it is a quote.

Comment: @JJosaur. Thanks for understanding my point! BW